# Customize email setting in PasswordResetView django

Tags: django, email

I found a tutorial on how to include username when resetting the password using this [tutorial.](https://blog.puliyo.com/en/posts/override_password_form/) My question is how to customize the email sending function in PasswordResetView ? I already have my own customized email sending function but I dont know how to connect it. Another thing is, when email is sent, the FROM portion is not using the host that I setup in my settings.py

**UPDATE:** I added this send_email function here on my form. How do I trigger this from my view?

setings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mailtrap.io'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxxxxx'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_PORT = '2525'
```

How I send email:

```
def SendEmail(mail_subject, mail_message, mail_to):

    context = {}

    try:
        send_mail(mail_subject, mail_message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [mail_to], html_message=mail_message, fail_silently=False)
        return HttpResponse("SUCCESS")

    except BadHeaderError:
        context['message'] = "Email has encountered some problems."
        return HttpResponse("SUCCESS")
```

forms.py:

```
class MyPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=254)
    field_order = ['username', 'email']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyPasswordResetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {'class': 'user-input-form'}


    def send_mail(self, subject_template_name, email_template_name,
                context, from_email, to_email, html_email_template_name=None):

        print(from_email)
        print(to_email)
        """
        Send a django.core.mail.EmailMultiAlternatives to `to_email`.
        """
        subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, context)
        # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
        subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
        body = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)

        email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, from_email, [to_email])
        if html_email_template_name is not None:
            html_email = loader.render_to_string(html_email_template_name, context)
            email_message.attach_alternative(html_email, 'text/html')

        email_message.send()
```

views.py

```
class MyPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
    form_class = MyPasswordResetForm

    def form_valid(self, form):


        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email', '').lower()
        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(username=username, email=email)
        except(get_user_model().DoesNotExist):
            user = None
        if user is None:
            return redirect('password_reset_done')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

First remove the `def send_mail` function of my form `class MyPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):` since it is not needed (on my case).

Next do this on url:

```
path('reset_password/', views.MyPasswordResetView.as_view(
    template_name="../templates/logauth/reset_password.html",                # ADD THIS
    subject_template_name='../templates/logauth/password_reset_subject.txt', # ADD THIS
    email_template_name='../templates/logauth/password_reset_email.html',    # ADD THIS
    from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,),                                   # ADD THIS
    name="reset_password"),
```

It took so long to figure this out since this answer was not on any articles that I found.